# Having problem publishing Maui App for iOS (Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_SSLCopyALPNProtocols...)

Tags: maui, publish

I'm trying to publish an iOS App from Visual Studio on Windows. I can build in the Simulator, but cannot publish. I have followed these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs

When I come to publishing (right click project -> publish) I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_SSLCopyALPNProtocols",
referenced from _AppleCryptoNative_SslGetAlpnSelected in
libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.a(pal_ssl.c.o)
"_SSLCopyDistinguishedNames", references from:
_AppleCryptoNative_SslCopyCADistiguishedNames in
libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.a(pal_ssl.c.o)
"_SSLCopyPeerTrust", referenced from
_AppleCryptoNative_SslCopyCertChain in
libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.a(pal_ssl.c.o)
_AppleCryptoNative_SsllsHostnameMatch in
libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.a (pal_ssl.c.o)
"_SSLCreateContext", referenced from
_AppleCryptoNative_SslGetCipherSuite in
libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple.a (pal_ssl.c.o)
"_SSLGetNegotiatedProtocolVersion", referenced from
_AppleCryptoNative_SslGetProtocolVersion in libSystem.Se
```

I've tried setting a new minimum sdk and redoing the steps from Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried deploying on a physical iOS device in release mode?

Comment: I have tried it now, it gives the same error as above. In       _AppleCryptoNative_SslGetProtocolVersion in libSystem.Se FlyoutPageSample C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets 1559

Comment: Have you checked the [link behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/linking?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs#linker-behavior)?